# Does the mass of a galaxy change over its lifecycle?

Tags: mass, galaxies

I expect there is change as energy converts into matter and matter converts into energy. Is there an overall curve we have seen through observation that a galaxy goes through in its lifecycle or does it stay relatively flat?

Comment: FWIW, processes which convert energy to matter are rather rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galaxies grow over time from accretion of gas from the intergalactic medium. As observed in the Hubble Deep Field early galaxies were small. Simulations have shown that gas accretion is the primary process of galactic growth (e.g. Keres et al. 2005, Benson & Bower 2011). Direct evidence for gas accretion has been observed (Lehner et al. 2013, Crighton et al. 2013).

Keres et al., 2005, MNRAS,.363:2-28;
Benson & Bower, 2011, MNRAS, 410, 2653-2661;
Lehner et al., 2013, ApJ, 770, 138;
Crighton et al., ApJL, 2013, 776, L18.